# How to disable xml highlight in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to disable background highlights of xml  in intellij.

[image]

So far I've tried:

Editor > Inspections > disable xml

Editor > Language injections > disable xml

Editor > Color scheme > diasble background and foreground of all elements.

UPD

After disabling the Background of the Injected language fragment, I still have some brown background.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General, disable the **Background** of the **Injected language fragment**:

[image: fragment]

See also [the help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html) explaining what is language injection.

Comment: Yellow background is gone, but I still has some brown one. How do I remove that as well?