# Problem with Intellij color scheme on FXML file

Tags: intellij-idea, fxml, color-scheme

How can i change the color behind the code in FXML files in Intellij?

[See the Yellow color behind the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3AKq.png)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/57402067/104891 help?

Comment: No, i tryed that before, still the same.

Comment: Did you try changing the background of these elements: https://i.imgur.com/ohFAwyO.png
https://i.imgur.com/uTcWDCP.png
https://i.imgur.com/A6RiP3t.png ?

Comment: The first one worked, ive been searching in the wrong place, thank you <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the background color of the XML tags at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | XML:

[image: Tag background]